# Angular not showing error validation on input that's visibility is dependent on another input

Tags: angularjs

I'm experiencing a problem whereby the validation messaging doesn't seem to be firing for the below input. The appearance of this input is entirely dependent on another input (i.e. only show if they're still at school). What I've noticed is that, when I remove the `ng-if` regarding the display of this input, the validation messaging is fine and happens straight away. When `ng-if` is present however, it only shows the message if the value selected is invalid when `ng-if` has been satisfied. Any ideas?

***HTML***

```
<div ng-if="showSchoolLeavingYear()">
    <label for="ddlSchoolLeavingYear">School leaving year:</label>
    <select name="schoolLeavingYear" id="ddlSchoolLeavingYear" ng-model="session.form.schoolLeavingYear" required> 
        <option value="">- Please select -</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
    </select>
    <div class="ng-hide" validation-message field="schoolLeavingYear">Please select your school leaving year.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ng-if` asserts to false it removes the entire `<div>` from the DOM. Use `ng-show` so that the validation on those input fields still happens. Furthermore you need to close the `<div>` tag of the `ng-if/ng-show` so that it does not aply to the nested "error message div" like so:

```
<div ng-show="showSchoolLeavingYear()">
    <label for="ddlSchoolLeavingYear">School leaving year:</label>
    <select name="schoolLeavingYear" id="ddlSchoolLeavingYear" ng-model="session.form.schoolLeavingYear" required> 
        <option value="">- Please select -</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="ng-hide" validation-message field="schoolLeavingYear">Please select your school leaving year.</div>
```

Comment: Cheers, changed to `ng-show` and it worked. Is there an alternative solution for if I ***do*** want the `div` removed from the DOM?

Comment: @jumpingcode If you do want it to be removed but still want it to be included in the validation, I would suggest setting a variable in the controller script, whenever the div is evaluated. This way, even if the div is removed from the DOM you can still show the error message if validation before removal was not fulfilled. Also check my "edit" of the div nesting.